# sort informations from a file .txt using php

Tags: php, sorting, logfile

I use php in order to save all informations concerning my user (where do they navigated and at which time).

So I use the following code for saving informations:

```
<?php
function iif($condition, $true, $false ) {
    return ($condition ? $true : $false);
}

$ipaddress = $_SESSION['login'];
$page = "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}";
$page .= iif(!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']), "?{$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}", "");
$referrer = $monUrl = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$datetime = mktime();
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$remotehost = @getHostByAddr($ipaddress);

// Create log line
$logline = $ipaddress . '|' . $referrer . '|' . $datetime . '|' . $useragent . '|' . $remotehost . '|' . $page . "\n";
// Write to log file:
$logfile = 'logfile.txt';
$path='log/'.$_SESSION['login'].'/'.$logfile;
if(!file_exists($path)) {
mkdir('log');
mkdir('log/'.$_SESSION['login']);
$f = fopen('log/'.$_SESSION['login'].'/'.$logfile, "x+");
// fermeture
fclose($f);

}
// Open the log file in "Append" mode
if (!$handle = fopen($path, 'a+')) {
die("Failed to open log file");
}
// Write $logline to our logfile.
if (fwrite($handle, $logline) === FALSE) {
die("Failed to write to log file");
}
fclose($handle);

?>
```

And I use the following code below to display it:

```
                                   <?php 


$path= 'log/'.$data['login'].'/logfile.txt';
$logfile = $path;
if (file_exists($logfile)) {
$handle = fopen($logfile, "r");
$log = fread($handle, filesize($logfile));
fclose($handle);
} else {
die ("Le fichier de Log n'existe pas!");
}
// Seperate each logline
$log = explode("\n", trim($log));
//After that it may be useful to get each part of each logline in a separate variable. This can be done //by looping through each logline, and using explode again:
// Seperate each part in each logline
for ($i = 0; $i < count($log); $i++) {
$log[$i] = trim($log[$i]);
$log[$i] = explode('|', $log[$i]);
}

// Show a table of the logfile
echo '<table id="box-table-a">';
echo '<th scope="col">Agent</th>';
echo '<th scope="col">Referrer</th>';
echo '<th scope="col">Date</th>';
echo '<th scope="col">Useragent</th>';
echo '<th scope="col">Remote Host</th>';
foreach ($log as $logline) {
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><a href="index.php?p=voir_fiche_employee&id='.$_GET['id'].'"/>' . $logline['0'] . '</a></td>';
echo '<td><a href="'.urldecode($logline['1']).'"/>'. urldecode($logline['1']) . '</a></td>';
echo '<td>' . date('d-m-Y h:i:s', $logline['2']) . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $logline['3'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $logline['4'] . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

The trouble I met is that I really do not know how to sort informations from this file.
In fact on the top of the page I have a form in order to choose between the dates. I wsould like to display all informations from this logfile between those dates but I really do not know how to do.

At the beginning I was planning to save all in the databse, but somebody told me that it would have been too much for the databse, so I decided to save all in a txt on the server.

Does anyone know if it is possible to sort informations from txt file?

By default I would like to display informations of the logfile for the date of the day, and If I want I can choose an other dates or an interval of dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible to store data into a database.  It is easy to sort in database.  Reading data into a text file is more time consuming and difficult to sort.

Comment: it is very difficult to do.  You may need more memory to do

Comment: ok, I think I will turn back to mysql, Thank you verry much for your sincer answers It was verry helpfull for me to do a compromise between what I was expecting and What was possible to do